# install mamba on top of anaconda 2023.09 fresh reinstall

Tags: anaconda, conda, mamba

I am using Windows Server, and installed Anaconda v2023.09 as my environment. I wanted to install `mamba`, so I called

```bash
conda install mamba -c conda-forge
```

However, this process is almost taking forever. I wonder is there any kind of way I can accelerate such installation?

Before `mamba` installed, I realized it is now almost impossible to use `conda install` anything more on top since solving will take forever. But installing `mamba` itself would `conda` again.... Wondering if we can achieve anything like a fast installation.... (like an installation ignoring all depencies and only after `mamba` is installed, fixed the dependencies using mamba/ or pip install/ or some kind of manual install)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Do not install Mamba in Anaconda/Miniconda

It is no longer recommended to install `mamba` in an Anaconda or Miniconda **base**. However, Conda now uses the `libmamba` solver, so just upgrade your **base** `conda` to v23.11.0 or greater and it will run as fast as `mamba`.

```bash
## v23.11+ uses libmamba solver
conda install -n base -n defaults 'conda>=23.11'
```

The main problem currently is that `mamba` is only served from Conda Forge channel and Conda Forge packages require that channel to be prioritized. In practice that simply does not work with Anaconda **base**. The least painful resolution would be for Anaconda to build their own copy of `mamba` and serve it from the `anaconda` (`defaults`) channel.

More generally, one should simply not be installing anything from Conda Forge in Anaconda **base**.

### Consider Micromamba

A newer solution is [Micromamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/micromamba-installation.html) which is static and doesn't live in an environment. It is extremely useful for creating Conda environments without having to install a Conda **base** (such as provisioning in CI or containers). I expect more users will continue to adopt it since it properly separates the functionality of manipulating Conda environments from a Conda environment (**base**).

Comment: thanks for yet another amazing answer. Just wanted to say thanks for all of your help on issues with conda. I have learned a lot from your answers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One difficulty I faced is that I cannot upgrade the base conda to make use of libmamba, since it finds conflict as well. I don’t want to uninstall anaconda as I have already done a lot on top. However, I am thinking whether I can do some kind of prune force reinstall to convert my base into latest microconda environment.  Wondering if that could solve my problem.

Comment: Use Micromamba to update `conda` in the **base**.